# When should the topic challenges be ending?

Tags: discussion, challenge

Sorry for the kind of poll question but..

For the biweekly topic challenges, I've been ending the challenges on Monday, technically Sunday at midnight but I write the summary and post the new challenge on Monday morning. So any questions asked on Monday would be either a part of the next topic challenge, or just a 'normal' question.

It was mentioned that my wording on the challenges made it seem like they would end on Monday. Which would mean anything that happens on Monday could be a part of both challenges.

Does anybody have a preference as to when the challenges end / What kind of timeframe should the challenges follow?

Answer (score 3):

You are the main action provider and have been doing all the "Heavy Lifting".  What works best for you is the primary determinant of timing.

Also thank you for all your hard work on the challenges.

Comment: I'll second that, especially the thanks part of it. I've been so crazy busy at work recently that I've really just been poking my head in.

Answer (score 0):

I think it works best for the challenge to end on Monday - or rather, for the new challenge to be posted on Monday, so it's the same day every two weeks. But whatever works best for you really , it doesn't have to be strict.